# How include packajes dependencies in output directory/node_modules with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, tsc

I need add in output directory/ node_modules only de dependencies that exist in package.json

I tried this  "postbuild": "cp -R node_modules lib/node_modules",
but Copy all dependencies.

I need something like

Dist
-- node_modules --> include only dependencies of package.json
-- src
package.json